# Can you help me with an algorithm?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting, filter

I'm getting some nested data, that I need to filter out and I just can't wrap my head around all those loops. I would be very glad for a help.

Data I get:

```
const data = [
{
    categories: [{ name: "street" }, { name: "portrait" }],
    photo: { childImageSharp: { fluid: "values" } },
},
{
    categories: [{ name: "street" }],
    photo: { childImageSharp: { fluid: "values" } },
},
{
    categories: [{ name: "portrait" }],
    photo: { childImageSharp: { fluid: "values" } },
},
{
    categories: [{ name: "street" }, { name: "architecture" }],
    photo: { childImageSharp: { fluid: "values" } },
},
{
    categories: [{ name: "architecture" }],
    photo: { childImageSharp: { fluid: "values" } },
},
{
    categories: [{ name: "street" }],
    photo: { childImageSharp: { fluid: "values" } },
},
];
```

**List of photos**, each photo has a **photo object** with source that I ll use to render element and also **categories array of objects** that contains an **name** with string value.

And I want to filter out only photos that contains category name "portrait". So I need to create an new array that is filtered with only these results that match my criteria.

What I've tried:

```
const filtered = data.map((photo) => photo.categories.filter((category) => category.name.includes("portrait")));
```

What I got:

```
const result = [
  [{name: "portrait"}],
  [],
  [{name: "portrait"}],
  [],
  [],
  []
]
```

What I'd like to get:

```
const result = [
  {
    categories: [{ name: "street" }, { name: "portrait" }],
    photo: { childImageSharp: { fluid: "values" } },
  },
  {
    categories: [{ name: "portrait" }],
    photo: { childImageSharp: { fluid: "values" } },
  }
]
```

Comment: Start off using longhand loop's and gett it working longhand before starting to use LINQ style syntax it becomes a lot easier to debug and step through the code to see where it's going wrong you also are not fighting scopes so it's probably easier to understand for your code to work

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't have a clue what is a longhand loop or LINQ style syntax, but will check on that thank you!

Comment: then you need to go back to basics and learn how `for` loops work.

Comment: @Barkermn01 Javascript has no concept of LINQ - that's a purely .net concept. Not a great bit of advice for someone new to javascript, it's just confusing. Also telling them that they must go "back to basics" isn't very helpful advice. There's nothing at all wrong with this question - clear problem, an attempt to fix it, all code necessary to debug. I wish all questions were this good.

Comment: i said LINQ style, and it is `ObjectSet.QueryControls` and if you don't understand that that's a lack in your knowledge those filters and stuff are Javascript implementations of LINQ features, https://gist.github.com/DanDiplo/30528387da41332ff22b,

Comment: Secondly, if you don't know what Longhand code is your skipping critical knowledge my reason for that is it's remarkably harder to debug using Breakpoints those styles of queries versus the loops, if you have a problem with filters or anything like that sometimes taking it to the simpler version helps you understand why it was going wrong. if you don't even know how to expand them into longhand code that's a huge gap in programming knowledge, because it means you don't know what they are doing your going with "it's magic" and a programmer should understand how stuff works under the hood.

Comment: Oh, where do you think ECMA International got the idea for the methods from? LINQ there was a reason they came out after LINQ, the same as langs using the C syntax because it's good, it's called adaptation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use `map` just use `filter`

```js
const data = [
{
    categories: [{ name: "street" }, { name: "portrait" }],
    photo: { childImageSharp: { fluid: "values" } },
},
{
    categories: [{ name: "street" }],
    photo: { childImageSharp: { fluid: "values" } },
},
{
    categories: [{ name: "portrait" }],
    photo: { childImageSharp: { fluid: "values" } },
},
{
    categories: [{ name: "street" }, { name: "architecture" }],
    photo: { childImageSharp: { fluid: "values" } },
},
{
    categories: [{ name: "architecture" }],
    photo: { childImageSharp: { fluid: "values" } },
},
{
    categories: [{ name: "street" }],
    photo: { childImageSharp: { fluid: "values" } },
},
];

const result = data.filter( x => x.categories.some(c => c.name == "portrait"));
console.log(result);
```